# squeak(smalltalk) how to use method `findSubstring: in: startingAt: matchTable:`?

Tags: string, smalltalk, squeak

what I should send for `matchTable:` selector?

in the implementation, there are no examples or detailed explanation so 
I don't understand which object is getting the message if I put the string in `in:` selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `matchTable:` keyword provides a way to identify characters so that they become equivalent in comparisons. The argument is usually a `ByteArray` of `256` entries, containing at position `i` the code point of the `i`th character to be considered when comparing.

The main use of the table is to implement case-insensitive searches, where, e.g., `A=a`. Thus, instead of comparing the characters at hand during the search, what are compared are the elements found in the `matchTable` at their respective code points. So, instead of

```
   (string1 at: i) = (string2 at: j)
```

the testing becomes something on the lines of

```
   cp1 := string1 basicAt: i.
   cp2 := string2 basicAt: j.
   (table at: cp1) = (table at: cp2).
```

In other words, the `matchTable:` argument is used to map actual characters to the ones that actually matter for the comparisons.

Note that the same technique can be applied for case-sensitive/insensitive sorting.

Finally, bear in mind that this is a rather low-level method that non-system programmers would rarely need. You should be using instead higher level versions for finding substrings such as `findString:startingAt:caseSensitive:`, where the argument of the last keyword is a `Boolean`.

Comment: can I find subString with this method or just strings?

Comment: You can find any occurrence of a string inside another string. Substrings are strings, there is no difference between them. The term _substring_ refers to a string occurring inside another string. For instance, the string `'al'` is a substring of `'Smalltalk'` with two occurrences, one at index 3 and the other at index 7.